# JSON in Mysql and Unicode Hex

Tags: mysql, unicode

IN my mysql 5.7 database table there is a field description containing values like

`"{\"1\":\"Glasvlies  f\\u00fcr Gipskartonfugen\",\"2\":\"5 cm x 25 m Rolle\"}"`
I'd like to search for `für Gipskartonfugen` from a symfony 3.4 project.

I already tried with SQL-query:

`SELECT * FROM vendor_article v0_ WHERE v0_.description LIKE ?;`

WHERE description is `%für Gipskarton%` or `%f\\\\u00cfr Gipskarton%` or `%f\\u00cfr Gipskarton%` but don't get any results.

Same results with
`SELECT * FROM vendor_article v0_ WHERE CONCAT(v0_.description) LIKE ?;`

But when I search for
`SELECT * FROM vendor_article WHERE description LIKE '%\\u00%';`
I get results.

Comment: What type is your column?

Comment: Oh, sorry, i missed this. 
The field type is JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *client* issue at the time of `INSERTing`.  If you are using PHP, be sure to include `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` when calling `json_encode()`.  If you are using some other client, say so.

Comment: Seems you're right, but when I work next time on the project, I try to get this running with doctrine, because there is only one "normal" setter function:
`
 /**
     * Set description.
     *
     * @param json|null $description
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setDescription($description = null)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }`
There I can't override the json_encode function.
But when I manually set to `für` in Database, it works.

Comment: I found the error now. The problem was, that there was a transformer for this field. The transformer already encoded to JSON and put that into the json mysql field. So it was double json encoded. If someone still has the problem with the unicode-chars, either your installation setting is wrong or take a look here: https://zgadzaj.com/development/php/symfony/unescaped-json-doctrine-type

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.7 seems to have real problems with escaped Unicode in JSON. I initially though it was because the default character set is latin1, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
create table vender_article (
  description json not null
) character set utf8mb4;

insert into vender_article values ('"f\\u00fcr"'), ('"für"');

select * from vender_article;
```

[MySQL 5.7 gives](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=673827abb2e1aa75d752841ad50314bb) `null` and `"für"`. [MySQL 8.0 gives](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=673827abb2e1aa75d752841ad50314bb) `für` and `für`.

Try changing your [database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-database.html) or [server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-server.html) character set to `utf8mb4` and see if that helps. I can't do this on dbfiddle.

```
alter database <your database> character set utf8mb4 collation utf8_unicode_ci
```

Alternatively, unescape your JSON before inserting it.

Alternatively, update to MySQL 8. This will give many features and bug fixes including better Unicode and JSON support.

---

If you store the column as [`JSON`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) it will understand the unicode escapes.

This also gives you proper [JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html).

```
SELECT * FROM vendor_article where description->"$.*" like '%für Gipskartonfugen%';
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work in my case. I still doesn't get a result.

Comment: @sneaky My mistake, looks like this requires MySQL 8. I would strongly suggest upgrading if you can, MySQL 8 brings a great many good features and fixes.

Comment: @sneaky Does your JSON column have all those extra escapes and quotes in it? `select description from vender_article` should show `'{"1":"Glasvlies  f\u00fcr Gipskartonfugen","2":"5 cm x 25 m Rolle"}');` not `"{\"1\":\"Glasvlies  f\\u00fcr Gipskartonfugen\",\"2\":\"5 cm x 25 m Rolle\"}"`

Comment: On console it shows `"{\"1\":\"Glasvlies  f\\u00fcr Gipskartonfugen\",\"2\":\"5 cm x 25 m Rolle\"}"` in PHPStorm Database Console it shows `"{\"1\":\"Glasvlies  f\\u00fcr Gipskartonfugen\",\"2\":\"5 cm x 25 m Rolle\"}"`
The Database is already utf8mb4, the table is already utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
By the way the above written command must be `alter table vendor_article convert to character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;` in 5.7 this doesn't work on databases.